# after changing ruby version getting a frozenobject error

Tags: ruby, rspec, ruby-2.7, ruby-3

i have a code in ruby 2.7.2 where it is working fine.
but after changing ruby version to 3.0.0 it is giving cannot modify FrozenObject error at line 275.
as i have checked $? is a Frozen Object in ruby 3.0.0 but it is not Frozen in ruby 2.7.2 so what should i do? is there any alternative to this.

```
   272:     it 'returns the exitstatus of the command' do
   273:       allow(subject).to receive(:system)
   274:
=> 275:       allow($?).to receive(:exitstatus) { 42 }
   276:
   277: 
   278:       expect(subject.copy_to('local', 'remote')).to eq(42)
   279:     end

1) xxxxxxxxxx::InstanceSSH#copy_to returns the exitstatus of the command
 Failure/Error: allow($?.exitstatus).to receive(:exitstatus) { 42 }
 
 FrozenError:
   can't modify frozen object: pid 74171 exit 0
 # ./spec/cloudgate/instance_ssh_spec.rb:275:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # /home/lenovo/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/webmock-3.10.0/lib/webmock/rspec.rb:37:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Finished in 114 minutes 1 second (files took 1.81 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure

Comment: Can you provide some more context? There's probably an alternative way to write the test, but I can't say without knowing what the code being tested is.

Comment: The way `allow` works is to patch in methods using `extend`. If `$?` is read-only in Ruby 3.0 you can't do that any more.